# I recorded two finger pinch with getevent but when replaying it the touch cannot release

Tags: adb, touchscreen, gestures

I am trying to write some automation script for the Android emulator I am using. The emulator does provide simulation of pinches with keyboard and trackpad, but I would like to do it through the Android console, so I recorded the pinch with `getevent`, converted it to decimal and replay it with `sendevent`. I do observed the pinch but when it is done, the touch is not released and this mess up the simulations later on. I observe that if `BTN_TOUCH UP` event is send along with the pinch, it won't work. I cannot even do things like `sh zoom-out.sh && sleep 1 && sh release.sh` (assuming that I have the scripts to zoom out and releasing the touch in these 2 files). The only thing that works is through calling `sh zoom-out.sh` and then `sh release.sh` on a new line, which is wried to me.

Comment: you probably forgot *BTN_TOUCH=UP (014a=0)* make record of single tap only with *'getevent -lc10 /dev/input/event'*

Comment: @alecxs Yes, I do am missing the button up event, but I don't know why I cannot record that. My touch screen events are in event5 and when I `getevent -lc10 /dev/input/event` I see the button up event while in dev/input/event5, there isn't.

Comment: no need to record when you know whats missing

Comment: @alecxs That is right but I am new to Android and I see no documentation about sendevent, it doesn't even come with a help. Can you please point me to some resourses. I tried to resolve the macros with `getevent -lp /dev/input/event5` and I find `KEY` as 1, `BTN_TOUCH` as 257 or 258 depending on it starts at 0 or 1. However that doesn't help.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEeJ3.png

Comment: there is no documentation, only this [xda thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2233865) you probably know already